# Tensorflow Stored Learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I haven't tried Tensorflow yet but still curious, how does it store, and in what form, data type, file type, the acquired learning of a machine learning code for later use?

For example, Tensorflow was used to sort cucumbers in Japan. The computer used took a long time to learn from the example images given about what good cucumbers look like. In what form the learning was saved for future use?

Because I think it would be inefficient if the program should have to re-learn the images again everytime it needs to sort cucumbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, a high level way to think about a machine learning model is three components - the code for the model, the data for that model, and metadata needed to make this model run.

In Tensorflow, the code for this model is written in Python, and is saved in what is known as a GraphDef. This uses a serialization format created at Google called [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf). Common serialization formats include Python's native [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for other libraries.

The main reason you write this code is to "learn" from some training data - which is ultimately a large set of matrices, full of numbers. These are the "weights" of the model - and this too is stored using ProtoBuf, although other formats like [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) exist.

Tensorflow also stores Metadata associated with this model - for instance, what should the input look like (eg: an image? some text?), and the output (eg: a class of image aka - cucumber1, or 2? with scores, or without?). This too is stored in Protobuf.

During prediction time, your code loads up the graph, the weights and the meta - and takes some input data to give out an output. More information [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the symbolic math library, or the idea of tensor flow in general? Please be more specific here.

Here are some resources that discuss the library and tensor flow

These are some [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/)

And here is some background on the [field](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/first-steps-with-tensorflow/toolkit)

And this is the github [page](https://github.com/tensorflow)

If you want a more specific answer, please give more details as to what sort of work you are interested in.

**Edit**: So I'm presuming your question is more related to the general field of tensor flow than any particular application. Your question still is too vague for this website, but I'll try to point you toward a few resources you might find interesting.

The tensorflow used in image recognition often uses an *ANN* (*A*rtificial *N*eural *N*etwork) as the object on which to act. What this means is that the tensorflow library helps in the number crunching for the neural network, which I'm sure you can read all about with a quick google search.

The point is that tensorflow isn't a form of machine learning itself, it more serves as a useful number crunching library, similar to something like numpy in python, in large scale deep learning simulations. You should read more [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-introduction-machine-learning-tutorial/).

Comment: So, the learning is in the form of a model .. and Tensorflow helps you create this model?

Comment: That's one way to think about it. Tensorflow is a really powerful tool for Python and C++ developers because it allows them to avoid the nitty-gritty of the details of the calculations, and rather focus on the abstraction of the ML algorithm they are working on. It works really well in working with graphs, which happen to be the data structures of choice for a lot of ML applications, as well as some non ML ones.